# How to determine if a URL starts with numbers ends in a letter

Tags: php, url-rewriting, url-routing, digits, letter

I need to found a way to find out if the URL being requested is starting with 5 digits and ends with a letter

```
13373W
```

I know if I do this

```
(\d+)
```

it matches the numbers (digits) however once I had the W on the end of the string that no longer works.

I am wondering what is the correct way to do this - now as we get bigger and more people join, we will move to 6 numbers and so on, but the letter should always be at the end.

Comment: well if you have only one letter at the end, you can split the 12234W string to 12234 and W , and then use them however you want. 

But I have to admit it, your question cannot be understood very well, it would be best if you edit it to specify what you need.

Comment: dispatch_get("^/(\d+[A-Z])", array($redi, 'pet'));

Comment: is what you commented working or is it what you get error from?

Comment: no that is now working - I have approved the answer below - even knowing I fixed it myself with the above text. but @Barmar is also correct

Comment: Well, it's good to know you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression should be:

```
/\d+[A-Z]$
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

The answer I found was to use this code

```
dispatch_get("^/(\d+[A-Z])", array($redi, 'pet'));
```

Stupid me, more research would of showed me this.